# Array to string conversion when run eloquent command

Tags: laravel

Controller :

```
public function index(){
    $data = Personal::all();
    return view('frontend/dashboard');
}
```

Error :

> Array to string conversion

And also show :

> \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php:39

Comment: Its hard to see what the problem is from the snippet. Is there other code snippet that would help to understand the issue?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code in your `Personal` model and your view (blade file) too. A stack trace of the error would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 return view('frontend/dashboard');
```

to

```
 return view('frontend.dashboard');
```

please make sure your file name is dashboard.blade.php

Comment: there is no requirement to use the 'dot' notation to reference views and how does this relate to the 'array to string conversion' error?